# Is it possible to collect information about a running .jar file when it exits?

Tags: java, application-shutdown, shutdown-hook

is it possible to gather information on all the existing variables within a running .jar file when it exits? I'm running an application on the linux command line of various servers and I try to debug an issue when the jar just stops working on 10% of the systems.

In Android, there is a method called `onDestroy()` which can be overwritten in order to perform tasks when the app exits. Is there something similar possible in native Java applications? And even if that is the case, how could I collect the data?

Comment: *"Thanks for helping! s."* I'll thank you for leaving out such noise in future.

Comment: *"And even if that is the case, how could I collect the data?"*  Separate question.  Please put it on one.

Comment: "I'll thank you for leaving out such noise in future." -> To some it's noise, to others politeness. Additionally, I don't see why I should split this question, as my initial question is clear and needs two steps to be accomplished.

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a Social Network](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128552/155831).  *"I don't see why I should split this question.."*  Asking 2 questions & getting 1 answer is not enough of a hint for you?   A person may know the answer to one, but not the other.  Should that person avoid replying?

Comment: I guess the both of us won't come to an agreement here. But I thank you for the advice, even if it's noise for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In Android, there is a method called `onDestroy()`..

Add a [shutdown hook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29).